# My variable is not initialized but the code block is executed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my `QuizActivity` I have this code:

```
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   
    private int questionCounter;

    private int questionCountTotal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz); 

        questionCountTotal = questionList.size();

        showNextQuestion();

    }

    private void showNextQuestion() {

        rb1.setTextColor(textColorDefaultRb);
        rb2.setTextColor(textColorDefaultRb);
        rb3.setTextColor(textColorDefaultRb);
        rbGroup.clearCheck();

        if(questionCounter < questionCountTotal){
            currentQuestion = questionList.get(questionCounter);

            textViewQuestion.setText(currentQuestion.getQuestion());
            rb1.setText(currentQuestion.getOption1());
            rb2.setText(currentQuestion.getOption2());
            rb3.setText(currentQuestion.getOption3());

            questionCounter++;
            textViewQuestionCount.setText("Question: " + questionCounter + "/" + questionCountTotal);
            answered = false;
            buttonConfirmNext.setText("Confirm");

        }else{
            finishQuiz();
        }
    }

   
}
```

`questionCounter` is not initialize to `0 or to any int value` why is it the program is reading `if(questionCounter < questionCountTotal)`? the code block inside the if statement is executed, why is that? as far as I know, you can't compare values that is not initialized

It should crash the app while reading `if(questionCounter < questionCountTotal)`

Comment: You don't have to initialize fields (unless declared `final`). They're defaulted to 0.

Comment: I've tested that scenario in java console and it crashes why is that? @shmosel

Comment: You've tested what?

Comment: `if(questionCounter < questionCountTotal)` without initializing the `questionCounter` to any value and it crashes the app in java console. I've initialize `questionCountTotal to 10` @shmosel

Comment: `if(questionCounter < questionCountTotal){
            System.out.println("BOOM");
        }else{
            System.out.println("OUT");
        }`

Comment: `error: variable questionCounter might not have been initialized`

Comment: @shmosel. 0 only for int. Not for others

Comment: Variables are different from fields.

Answer (score 0):

`int`, `long`, `double`, `boolean`, `char` etc... are primitive type variables. They can never be null. They get these default values even if not initialised:

| Data Type | Default Value (for fields) |
| --- | --- |
| byte | 0 |
| short | 0 |
| int | 0 |
| long | 0L |
| float | 0.0f |
| double | 0.0d |
| char | '\u0000' |
| String | (or any object) null |
| boolean | false |

Now, when you check them and try to print them in log, you will see these values. But, on the same place, if you try to use objects without initialising them, you get a [NullPointerException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html?is-external=true)

Comment: `they get default values even if not initialized?` I've tried `int a;` and `int b = 10` and then compare them `if(a < b)` it crashes in `java console`.

Comment: is `java console` different from `android studio?`

Comment: Hmmm. Not exactly @JamesGosling. Android Studio uses java compiler. And it can be said as a `java console` for android apps development.

Comment: they get default values. And java console and Android Studio are different.